# Wix installer Radio Button issue - error LGHT0094 : Unresolved reference to symbol 'Property:'

Tags: installation, wix, wix3.11

I have inserted the following dialog in WixUI_InstallDir UI. it should populate two radio buttons. The expectation is based on the radio button input, the installer should install a selected feature.

```
    <Dialog Id="QCTypeDetailsDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="!(loc.InstallDirDlg_Title)">
        <Control Id="Description" Type="Text" X="25" Y="23" Width="280" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="Please select the type of QC to install." />
        <Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="15" Y="6" Width="200" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="QC Type" />
        <Control Id="BannerBitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="44" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.InstallDirDlgBannerBitmap)" />
        <Control Id="BannerLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="44" Width="370" Height="0" />
        <Control Id="BottomLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="0" />

        <Control Id="QCType" Type="RadioButtonGroup" Property="QC_TYPE" X="20" Y="80" Width="290" Height="18" Indirect="yes" >
            <RadioButtonGroup Property="QC_TYPE">
                <RadioButton Value="1" Text="QC EXT" X="20" Y="100" Width="90" Height="18" />
                <RadioButton Value="2" Text="QC Standard" X="20" Y="120" Width="90" Height="18"/>
            </RadioButtonGroup>
        </Control>
    
        <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUINext)" >
            <Publish Event="ADDLOCAL" Value="ALL">1</Publish>
            <Publish Event="Remove" Value="QC_EXT_Feature">0</Publish>
            <Publish Event="Remove" Value="QC_STD_Feature">1</Publish>
            <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" />
        </Control>
        
        <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="180" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.WixUIBack)" />
        <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUQCancel)">
            <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg">1</Publish>
        </Control>
    </Dialog>
```

While linking the wixobj with main program, The light command is throwing following error,

> error LGHT0094 : Unresolved reference to symbol 'Property:QC_TYPE' in
> section 'Fragment:'.

If define the property under Fragment, or in the main wxs file,

```
<Property Id="QC_TYPE" Value="1"/>
```

Then it throws the following error

> error LGHT0204 : ICE34: Property 1 must be defined because it is an indirect property of a RadioButtonGroup control QCTypeDetailsDlg.QCType.

I am not sure what is wrong with this dialog or the QC_TYPE property, any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is compiling properly after updated the RadioButtonGroup control property 'Indirect' value as 'no'

```
<Control Id="QCType" Type="RadioButtonGroup" Property="QC_TYPE" X="20" Y="80" Width="290" Height="18" Indirect="no" >
```